# how to set two columns recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/PetPhoto_imageview"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/PetItem_textview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dog" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/PetItem_textview"
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/PetPhoto_imageview"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"

        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="100" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

Those are my layout files, then picture below was they look like now, I want to set those pictures in two columns.

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to have the items in your recyclerview able to show in two columns. Try adding this when you set layoutManager

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
```

Comment: I need to add this in onCreate function under the activity corresponding to my xml file, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, i think you already have something that looks like it, but is setup with a LinearLayoutManager instead of the GridLayoutManager in this example,if you can't find it, try and update your question with your java code for the activity

Comment: Anytime! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 6):

Set from `xml` file add two property in `RecyclerView`

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
app:spanCount="2"
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager) to your RecyclerView with a span count 2.

Example:

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(manager);
```